# wxPython: get item count in DataViewListCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm writing a small app using wxPython on Python 2.7, and I use `DataViewListCtrl` to display some tabular data. I see in the [document of wxWidget](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_data_view_list_ctrl.html#a2e25697bbfed04db9d979e03e812ffc1) that it should have a `GetItemCount()` method to return the count of rows, but when I call this method in Python it gives a no attribute error:

> AttributeError: 'DataViewListCtrl' object has no attribute 'GetItemCount'

I then confirmed with `inspect.getmembers()` that this method is missing from the class. Any ideas why this would happen? How can I get the item count in the control? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `GetModel().GetItemCount()`, at least this should work in C++, but I didn't test it in Python.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `GetModel().GetItemCount()` and `GetStore().GetItemCount()`, but all resulted in same error.

Comment: To be more specific, both `GetModel()` and `GetStore()` worked as normal, but neither derived object has the method of `GetItemCount()`.